# Building html5 apps using ionic for ios

Tags: ios, html, webview, swift, ionic-framework

So I have an iOS app that i am writing with Swift. What i have done is created a bridge between the HTML5 web components and Swift so seamless communication takes place in between those. To be more specific, I have a web-view which loads files from the main bundle. So far, the way it is working is i have the main html file say index.html and all js files within the same folder for my webview to be able to load the html files and js resources. E.g. in my index.html file only something like this would work

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

and not

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I tried to do that with a sample Ionic app and realised that it has far too many dependencies and it would be a lot more work to include them all in the same folder. So how do  i go about solving this?  6 beta using Swift, which has a webview that shows a sample ionic app. So i can get to know how to configure the webview with HTML resources, swiping gestures etc.

fyi, My Swift code loads the index.html file as follows

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html");
```

I know there is a inDirectory parameter in pathForResource called inDirectory, but i cannot get it do work.

I have looked at a few questions about Ionic and they do not seem to be focusing on this problem. I think my issue is more about iOS then it is about Ionic.

Bhuman

Comment: I saw your post on the ionic forum. Post your  answer here so that others can benefit from the knowledge :)

Comment: Also, I just checked out your Xcode project. Pretty sweet, but how would you go about supporting android native code?

Comment: I am working on an iOS app and so that is why I solved a problem for it. I am not working on an Android app and have no plans to create a similar repo for Android anytime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @entitlement, so I do not remember my exact answer on the Ionic framework, forums but I have solved the problem I have talked about in this question and created a repo on Github for it which is basically an open-source template for building "native" Html5/iOS apps.

It's called [Html5StarterAppWithSwift](https://github.com/cptdanko/Html5StarterAppWithSwift)

If you would like to make any changes or have anything to contribute to it, then please fork it or create an issue for what you would like to see in that repo, and I will see what I can do.